# How to plot random number exponential distribution in Ruby with the Nyaplot?

Tags: ruby, random, rubygems

I'm having a really hard time graphing the following exponential distribution using [nyaplot](http://nbviewer.ipython.org/github/domitry/nyaplot/blob/master/examples/notebook/Introduction.ipynb)...

```
require 'distribution'

# use the same rng for each call
rng = Random

1.step(5, 0.1) do |mean|
  lambda = mean**-1

  # sample a value
  sample = Distribution::Exponential.p_value(rng.rand, lambda)
end
```

It should be a scattered graph:

Comment: This makes no sense to me.  You appear to be taking a single sample from each of 41 different exponential distributions, what are you expecting to get or trying to accomplish by this?

Comment: I'm attempting to plot the numbers. Perhaps I should iterate through the sample to show all values.